# Fundamental system of solutions for SLAE

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

> Given a SLAE $\left\{\begin{matrix}
> 5x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3}+6x_{4}=0\\ 
> x_{1}+3x_{2}-2x_{3}+4x_{4}=0\\ 
> 3x_{1}+2x_{2}-2x_{3}+5x_{4}=0\\ 
> 4x_{1}+5x_{2}-4x_{3}+9x_{4}=0
> \end{matrix}\right.$

Check if the rows of matrices A and B given below form a fundamental solution of SLAE.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 8 & 14 & 0\\ 
2 & 4 & 7 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ $\hspace{0.5mm}$ $B=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & 0 & 1\\ 
4 & 8 & 14 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

I found the row reduced echelon form of the coefficient matrix for the homogeneous SLAE as the following:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{-2}{7} & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & \frac{-4}{7} & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

But am confused on how to relate it with the matrices A and B?

Can you please let me know the correct approach for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rang of your system is $2$ and the dimension of the space of variables is $2$, solutions of the system form a $4-2 = 2$-dimensional subspace. Fundamental solution is a basis of this subspace. So you should check whether rows of $A$ and $B$ provide solutions to the system or not. Then, in the first case, you should prove or disprove that they are linearly independent. If they actually are, they form a fundamental system by the dimensionality argument.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.